# Is there a way to dynamically use res.render with a url parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to dynamically load a page with varying url parameters in the form of `?parameter=12345`, but I get the response `Failed to lookup view "account/signup?parameter=12345" in views directory`, which probably means that it is literally looking for an exact match of that view template, including the parameter aspect. Is there a way that I can render the page with that parameter inside of the following signup code:

```
exports.getSignup = function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) return res.redirect('/');
  try{
    headerString = req.headers.referer;
    headerString =  headerString.match(/\?(.*)/)[0] 
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }

  res.render('account/signup' + headerString, {
    title: 'Create Account',
    savedTripId: headerString
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can just render without mentioning the `headerString` in the url

```
exports.getSignup = function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) return res.redirect('/');
  try{
    headerString = req.headers.referer;
    headerString =  headerString.match(/\?(.*)/)[0] 
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }

  res.render('account/signup', {
    title: 'Create Account',
    savedTripId: headerString
  });
};
```

And since it seems you are using JADE you can do something like this on the client side

```
form(action="/formsubmit/#{headerString}")
    // form elements
    .
    .
    .
```

This renders it as

```
form(action="/formsubmit/1234")
    // form elements
    .
    .
    .
```

Then when the form is submitted you can get the header back on the server side as follows

```
app.post('/formsubmit/:headerString', function(req, res){

    var tripId = req.params.headerString;
    var formData = req.body; // if you are using body parser middleware
    // now you know which tripId has to be saved and have the form data. Perform actions accordingly

})
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. That's the line of thinking I was going down, only I was going to do something like     `window.location.href+= #{savedTripId}`...the problem is that for some reason it will understand what savedTripId is if I do something like   `h1 #{savedTripId}`, but it doesn't work for `window.location.href+= #{savedTripId}` under a script tag. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want `window.location.href`. And if that does not work why don't you use something like `h1 #{savedTripId}` and then hide the `h1` using `display: none` and then `window.location.href += $("h1").text()`

Comment: That's pretty clever :) nice